# Quarkus Kotlin: how to inject a CoroutineDispatcher

Tags: kotlin, sonarqube, kotlin-coroutines, quarkus

I have a Quarkus/Kotlin codebase implemented reactively (using coroutines, with `suspend` functions).

I need to call a blocking method from a non-blocking method.

The best solution I found, was inspired by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66412090/9135945):

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class MyService (
    private val blockingApi: BlockingApi
) {
    suspend fun nonBlocking() {
        val res: Response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            blockingApi.getResponse()
        }
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

This compiles and works as expected but [SonarQube](https://docs.sonarqube.org) detects here a codesmell:

> Avoid hardcoded dispatchers.

it references the [inject dispatchers](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#inject-dispatchers) part of the Android coroutines best practices documentation.

When I try to implement the suggestion of SonarQube:

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class MyService (
    private val blockingApi: BlockingApi,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) {
    suspend fun nonBlocking() {
        val res: Response = withContext(dispatcher) {
            blockingApi.getResponse()
        }
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

it throws a RuntimeException during the start of Quarkus:
`[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type com.example.myApp.some.MyService and qualifiers [@Default]`

And my IDE says it can't find any bean matching the injection.

[image: IDE: Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point]

Is there a way how I can make this dispatcher injection work?
Or is the reference by SonarQube only concerning Android and I can safely ignore it in a Quarkus project?

Comment: You could create CDI producer method for `CoroutineDispatcher` in order to get over the error Quarkus gives you.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75913695/quarkus-kotlin-how-to-inject-a-coroutinedispatcher?noredirect=1#comment133903351_75913695) of geoand and came up with this working solution:

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class Producers {
    @Produces
    fun getCoroutineDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher {
        return Dispatchers.IO
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class MyService (
    private val blockingApi: BlockingApi,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) {
    suspend fun nonBlocking() {
        val res: Response = withContext(dispatcher) {
            blockingApi.getResponse()
        }
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

See: [Quarkus CDI reference - Simplified Producer Method Declaration](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#simplified-producer-method-declaration)